# How to do pagination of data fetch from database in laravel in the backend

Tags: php, laravel

I have 6 different tables in my database and I fetch some values from each table from the database now I have to do the pagination in the backend i.e. I want to display according to page number and page per post like if I pass parameter like page_number and count my api would return exact number of posts of on that page_number. The count is for the cumulative count of posts i.e. it includes all 6 category posts name $u_article, $u_meetup, $u_job, $u_question, $u_event, $u_education.

```
public function wsUserActivity(){
    $request = Input::all();
    try {
        $user_id = $request['user_id'];
        $no=isset($request['page_number'])?$request['page_number']:0;
        $nos=isset($request['count'])?$request['count']:10;
        $skp=$no*$nos;
        $array_json_return = array('status' => '1','msg' => 'Success');


        $u_article = array();
        $u_article = DB::table('mst_article as article')
        ->select('id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1')
        ->get();

        if (count($u_article)>0){
            foreach ($u_article as $key => $value){
                $u_article[$key]->type = 'article';
                if (!empty($value->profile_image)){ 
                $u_article[$key]->profile_image_url = config("feature_image_path").'article_image/thumb/'.$value->profile_image;
                }
                $u_article[$key]->post_url = url('/') . '/view-article' .  '/' . $value->id;
            }
        }
        foreach ($u_article as $object){
            $u_articles[] = (array) $object;
        }

        $u_meetup = array();
        $u_meetup = DB::table('mst_meetup as meetup')
        ->select('id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(start_date, "%d %b %Y") as start_date'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image', 'location')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1')
        ->get();

        if (count($u_meetup)>0){
            foreach ($u_meetup as $key => $value){
                $u_meetup[$key]->type = 'meetup';
                if (!empty($value->profile_image)){
                $u_meetup[$key]->profile_image_url = config("feature_image_path").'meetup_image/thumb/'.$value->profile_image;
                }
                $u_meetup[$key]->post_url = url('/') . '/view-meetup' .  '/'  . $value->id;
            }
        }
        foreach ($u_meetup as $object){
            $u_meetups[] = (array) $object;
        }

        $u_question = array();
        $u_question = DB::table('mst_question as question')
        ->select('id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1')
        ->get();

        if (count($u_question)>0){
            foreach ($u_question as $key => $value){
                $u_question[$key]->type = 'question';
                if (!empty($value->profile_image)){
                $u_question[$key]->profile_image_url = config("feature_pic_url").'question_image/thumb/'.$value->profile_image;
                }
                $u_question[$key]->post_url = url('/') . '/view-question' .  '/'  . $value->id;
            }
        }
        foreach ($u_question as $object){
            $u_questions[] = (array) $object;
        }

        $u_job = array();
        $u_job = DB::table('mst_job as job')
        ->select('id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image', 'job_location', 'cmp_name')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1')
        ->get();

        if (count($u_job)>0){
            foreach ($u_job as $key => $value){
                $u_job[$key]->type = 'job';
                if (!empty($value->profile_image)){
                $u_job[$key]->profile_image_url = config("feature_pic_url").'job_image/thumb/'.$value->profile_image;
                }
                $u_job[$key]->post_url = url('/') . '/view-job' .  '/'  . $value->id;
            }
        }
        foreach ($u_job as $object){
            $u_jobs[] = (array) $object;
        }

        $u_education = array();
        $u_education = DB::table('mst_education as education')
        ->select('id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1')
        ->get();

        if (count($u_education)>0){
            foreach ($u_education as $key => $value){
                $u_education[$key]->type = 'education';
                if (!empty($value->profile_image)){
                $u_education[$key]->profile_image_url = config("feature_pic_url").'education_image/thumb/'.$value->profile_image;
                }
                $u_education[$key]->post_url = url('/') . '/view-education' .  '/' . $value->id;
            }
        }
        foreach ($u_education as $object){
            $u_educations[] = (array) $object;
        }

        $u_event = array();
        $u_event= DB::table('mst_event as event')
        ->select('id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(start_date, "%d %b %Y") as start_date'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image', 'location')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1')
        ->get();

        if (count($u_event)>0){
            foreach ($u_event as $key => $value){
                $u_event[$key]->type = 'event';
                if (!empty($value->profile_image)){
                $u_event[$key]->profile_image_url = config("feature_pic_url").'event_image/thumb/'.$value->profile_image;
                }
                $u_event[$key]->post_url = url('/') . '/view-event' .  '/' . $value->id;
            }
        }
        foreach ($u_event as $object){
            $u_events[] = (array) $object;
        }

        $u_activity = array();
        $u_activity = array_merge($u_articles, $u_meetups, $u_questions, $u_jobs, $u_educations, $u_events);


        $array_json_return['u_activity'] = $u_activity;


    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $array_json_return = $this->api_default_fail_response(__function__, $e);
    }

    echo json_encode($array_json_return);
}
```

I have tried this

```
            $u_article = array();
        $u_article = DB::table('mst_article as article')
        ->select('id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1')
        ->get();
```

but it is giving posts per page for each separate category not the cumulative category

Comment: It would be helpful if you could reduce your code to the minimum needed to reproduce your problem. Could you also explain the problem with what you've tried so far? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have tried using       ' $u_article = array();
        $u_article = DB::table('mst_article as article')
        ->select('id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1')->skip($skp)->take($nos)
        ->get();' but it is taking count and page_number of each category not the cumulative one.

Comment: It's difficult to read code in a comment. Please edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer Laravel Pagination with Laravel DB Object or Eloquent Model.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination